# How to give logged in users more content availability in Joomla 3+?

Tags: permissions, joomla-user-groups

I am new to Joomla, so this might be a very simple question, but I find it hard to access the information required.

I have made the basic site, and I have added the login form already. Furthermore I have created a new user group, with the restricted permissions.

Basically the site is for an artist who owns a school. The basic site will contain some information about the school, but existing students should be able to login, and if they do, have access to a page with some links to download extra learning material, in the form of pdf files.

If I login using the new student user to test the site, the page opens with some basic information about the user profile itself. Naturally that is not what I want. I would like the new page displayed, and the student should not be able to edit anything. If anyone here can give me some advice it would be great - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the users to the basic registered user group and in your login module and or menu item it will allow you to choose a redirect after successful login and logout. Simply choose the page your are referring to.